# Unrecognized angular component "app-navbar" while running ng-test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript

Failed: Template parse errors: 'app-navbar' is not a known element

1. If 'app-navbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-navbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message:

> ("[ERROR ->]<app-navbar></app-navbar>"): 
>      ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@0:0 
>      Error: Template parse errors:

Answer (score 1):

These errors usually mean you didn't declare the component in the module. **You need to include `app-navbar` in your test's module**, otherwise, the parent component is unaware of its child's existence and - therefore - it is "not a known element".

See more about modules here: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules

```
// Import it in your test
import { NavBar } from '<location>';

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    ...,
    // Add the child element to the declarations
    declarations: [ Navbar ],
    ...
  });
});
```